# I am coding with CodeHS Karel the Dog and I'm having trouble making Karel stop when frontIsBlocked

Tags: karel

So my code is

```
function start(){
    while(frontIsClear()) {
        move();
    }
    yesWall();
    noWall();
}


function placeBall() {
    putBall();
}

function yesWall() {
    while (frontIsBlocked()) {
        putBall();
        turnLeft();
        move();
        turnRight();
    }
}


function noWall() {
    while (frontIsClear()) {
        turnLeft();
        move();
        turnRight();
        yesWall();
    }
}
```

This makes Karel the Dog place a ball when the frontIsBlocked and moves up. When the front is cleared, he moves up and repeats the yesWall function. However I'm having trouble at the end where he places a ball and then he moves. Which I don't want him to do. I want him to just turnLeft. I've placed a GIF showing what is happening. 
[image]

I just don't know what to do now. I know that using the frontIsBlocked condition wasn't a good idea but that was the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where Karel's hitting the wall, put an if statement.

```
function yesWall() {
    while (frontIsBlocked()) {
        putBall();
        turnLeft();
        if(frontIsBlocked()){
            break;
        }
        move();
        turnRight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you went to the wall, then turned left, and went straight, putting balls... like this:

```
function start() {
    moveToWall();
    decorateFence();
}

function moveToWall() {
    while(frontIsClear()) {
        move();
    }
}

function decorateFence() {
    while(frontIsClear()){ //Since karel should not bump into the wall at any cost, put this while  front is clear first
        if(rightIsBlocked()) {
            putBall();
            move();
        }else{
            move(); //this way, karel is already pointing north, and if the right is blocked(if there's a fence) then a ball is put and karel moves, if there is no fence there, then karel moves anyway. 
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
function start(){
    while(frontIsClear()){
        move();
    }   
    turnLeft();

    while(frontIsClear()){

        if(rightIsBlocked()){
            putBall();
            move();
            while(rightIsClear()){
                move();
            }

        }
        if(frontIsBlocked()){
            putBall();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function start(){
    while(frontIsClear()) {
        move();
    }
    turnLeft();
    while(frontIsClear()){
        if(rightIsBlocked()){
             putBall();
            move();
        }else{
            move(); 
        }
    }
    putBall();
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22355127)